# Linq to SQL Join and Where

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have Users->Orders tables (one to many) and would like to select all users which have specified Orders. I have tried Linq below but it fails with error. How to write such Linq query?

```
DataAccess.Instance.Users.Where(p => p.Orders.Where(o => o.ProductId == productId))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try:

```
DataAccess.Instance.Users.Where(p => p.Orders.Any(o => o.ProductId == productId))
```

Note that the second `Where` is changed to `Any` which returns a boolean value and satisfies the type of the expression tree expected by the first `Where`: `Where` needs a condition, not a set of values retrieved from elsewhere.